# OpenLDAP server not working through ldap:// protocol

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a vanilla Scientific Linux 6.6 install (essentially RHEL 6.6) which I am trying to set up as an LDAP server. I have installed `openldap-servers` and started slapd with `service slapd start`. This default creates come configuration files in `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/` which, as I understand it is the newer config format.

To add a root user and password I created a file rootuser.ldif as (passwords changed of course):

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}n/y444ydfghRfgOzTGwh4A47Ih4Ek9fg

dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}n/y444ydfghRfgOzTGwh4A47Ih4Ek9fg
-
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
-
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com
```

and ran `ldapmodify -a -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f test.ldif` (based on the answer at [Basic openldap setup using slapd.d configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/587721/basic-openldap-setup-using-slapd-d-configuration)) while logged in as root on the server.

This works and returns:

```
modifying entry "olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config"

modifying entry "olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config"
```

To check that it worked I can do `ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b "olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config" olcRootDN` which returns:

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: olcRootDN 
#

# {2}bdb, config
dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

However, if I want to search using the ldap:// protocol (as I will need to when connecting remotely from clients or to connect phpldapadmin) I get an error. Running `ldapsearch -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -W` and entering the password as earlier just gives:

```
ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Adding on `-d5 -v` to the `ldapsearch` command gives a whole load of output:

```
ldap_initialize( <DEFAULT> )
ldap_create
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP localhost:389
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying ::1 389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect: 
connect success
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({i) ber:
ber_flush2: 78 bytes to sd 3
ldap_result ld 0x7bc270 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x7bc270 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x7bc270 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x7bc270 Connections:
* host: localhost  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Fri Feb  6 13:29:49 2015


** ld 0x7bc270 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x7bc270 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x7bc270 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x7bc270 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x7bc270 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x7bc270 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x7bc270 msgid 1 all 1
ber_get_next
ldap_err2string
ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_free_connection 1 1
ldap_free_connection: actually freed
```

I'm pretty sure that the server is running on port 389 as `telnet localhost 389` gives:

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

If I run `slapd` manually and set `-d-1` then I see the following output when I try to access it through ldap://

```
54d4dfec daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
54d4dfec daemon: activity on:54d4dfec 
54d4dfec slap_listener_activate(7): 
54d4dfec daemon: epoll: listen=7 busy
54d4dfec daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
54d4dfec >>> slap_listener(ldap:///)
54d4dfec daemon: listen=7, new connection on 12
54d4dfec daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
54d4dfec daemon: activity on:54d4dfec 
54d4dfec daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
54d4dfec daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
54d4dfec fd=12 DENIED from unknown (127.0.0.1)
54d4dfec daemon: closing 12
```

Is there perhaps some ACL that I need to set up to allow the `olcRootDN` to be allowed to query the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem as being caused by `/etc/hosts.allow`. I added

```
slapd: 127.0.0.1
```

to the end of that file and I am now getting "Invalid credentials" error instead which is likely a different problem.